# LINQ2SQL Where Clause Issues

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I cannot get the following linq query to work in vb.net. (SQLite database). If I take out the where clause it works. With the where clause I get an "argumentexception was unhandled (New)" error. It is a simple where clause! What can be wrong?

```
    Dim testList = (From tp In dc.testParam _
                    Join jctp In dc.jobCodetestParam On tp.testParamId Equals jctp.testParamId _
                    Join jc In dc.jobCode On jc.jobCode Equals jctp.jobCode _
                    Join p In dc.patient On p.jobCode Equals jc.jobCode _
                    Where p.patientId = 20 _
                    Select tp.testDescriptor).ToList()
```

Comment: But does it return anything if you do use 'where' ?

Comment: When you try it without `.ToList()` I mean. Also what type is `p.patientId` ?

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: If I take out where, it works, I get data. With or without ToList does not work with where clause. p.patientId is integer.